# basic singly-linked list in rust

Tags: beginner, linked-list, rust

I'm new to rust and tried to implement a singly-linked list as exercise.

Is this code so far suitable to solve the problem? What elements of the language should I consider to make the code more elegant?

````rust
#![allow(dead_code)]

use std::{
    fmt::{Debug, Display},
    ops::Index,
};

struct List {
    value: u8,
    next: Option<Box<List>>,
}

impl List {
    fn new(value: u8) -> Self {
        let next = None;
        Self { value, next }
    }

    fn append(&mut self, value: u8) {
        let new = List::new(value);
        let last = self.get_last_element_mut();
        last.next = Some(Box::new(new));
    }

    fn get_last_element_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        if self.next.is_none() {
            self
        } else {
            self.next.as_mut().unwrap().get_last_element_mut()
        }
    }

    fn get_last_element(&self) -> &Self {
        if self.next.is_none() {
            self
        } else {
            self.next.as_ref().unwrap().get_last_element()
        }
    }

    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        if self.next.is_none() {
            1
        } else {
            1 + self.next.as_ref().unwrap().len()
        }
    }

    fn get_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut Self {
        if index == 0 {
            self
        } else {
            self.next.as_mut().unwrap().get_mut(index - 1)
        }
    }
}

impl Index<usize> for List {
    type Output = List;

    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        if index == 0 {
            self
        } else {
            &self
                .next
                .as_ref()
                .expect("line should have {index} more elements")[index - 1]
        }
    }
}

impl PartialEq for List {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.value == other.value && self.next == other.next
    }
}

impl Display for List {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        if self.next.is_none() {
            f.write_fmt(format_args!("{}", self.value))
        } else {
            f.write_fmt(format_args!("{} -> ", self.value))?;
            std::fmt::Display::fmt(&self.next.as_ref().unwrap(), f)
        }
    }
}

impl Debug for List {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f.debug_struct("List")
            .field("value", &self.value)
            .field("next", &self.next)
            .finish()
    }
}

impl From<Vec<u8>> for List {
    fn from(vec: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        let mut result = List::new(vec[0]);
        for item in &vec[1..] {
            result.append(*item);
        }
        result
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut l = List::new(5);
    l.append(8);
    l.append(1);
    println!("{}", l[0]);
    println!("{}", l[1]);
    println!("{}", l[2]);
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::List;

    #[test]
    fn append() {
        let mut l = List::new(5);

        assert_eq!(l.len(), 1);
        assert_eq!(l.get_last_element().value, 5);

        l.append(8);

        assert_eq!(l.len(), 2);
        assert_eq!(l.get_last_element().value, 8);
    }

    #[test]
    fn mutable() {
        let mut l = List::new(0);
        l.append(1);
        assert_eq!(l.get_last_element().value, 1);
        assert_eq!(l.len(), 2);

        l.get_last_element_mut().value = 5;
        assert_eq!(l.get_last_element().value, 5);
        assert_eq!(l.len(), 2);
    }

    #[test]
    fn representation() {
        let mut l = List::new(1);
        l.append(2);
        l.append(3);
        let repr = format!("{}", l);
        assert_eq!(repr, "1 -> 2 -> 3");
    }

    #[test]
    #[should_panic]
    fn out_of_bounds() {
        let mut l = List::new(1);
        l.append(2);
        let _ = l[l.len()];
    }

    #[test]
    fn from_vec() {
        let input = vec![0, 3, 2, 1, 4];
        let list = List::from(input);
        let repr = format!("{}", list);
        assert_eq!(repr, "0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4");
    }
}

```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is generally well-formatted and readable.
Also, kudos for including unit tests
since they make it easy for reviewers to tweak and test your code.

> ```rust
> #![allow(dead_code)]
> ```

The reason why you got dead code warnings
is (mostly like) because you did not mark public interfaces as `pub`.
Instead of suppressing the warning,
you should mark `struct List` and its methods as `pub`.

> ```rust
> struct List {
>     value: u8,
>     next: Option<Box<List>>,
> }
> ```

We can easily generalize the code to handle non-`u8` element types:

```rust
struct List<T> {
    value: T,
    next: Option<Box<List<T>>>,
}
```

> ```rust
> fn new(value: u8) -> Self {
>     let next = None;
>     Self { value, next }
> }
> ```

A simpler alternative is `Self { value, next: None }`.

> ```rust
> fn get_last_element_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
>     if self.next.is_none() {
>         self
>     } else {
>         self.next.as_mut().unwrap().get_last_element_mut()
>     }
> }
> ```

Here, we see the common anti-pattern `is_none` + `unwrap`,
which appears throughout the code a few times.
The latter (in theory) performs a redundant second check for `is_none`
and leaves the impression that a panic is possible.
The way to go here is to use a `match` directly:

```rust
fn get_last_element_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
    match self.next {
        None => self,
        Some(ref mut next) => next.get_last_element_mut(),
    }
}
```

(It seems that combinators such as `map_or` cannot be used here
since `self.next.as_deref_mut().map_or(self, Self::get_last_element_mut)`
would alias the mutable reference `self`.)

I would, however, also consider going with an iterative version
to prevent unnecessary recursion:

```rust
fn get_last_element_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
    let mut last = self;
    while let Some(ref mut next) = last.next {
        last = next;
    }
    last
}
```

> ```rust
> impl Index<usize> for List {
>     type Output = List;
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```

I would expect `type Output = usize`
(or `type Output = T` for a generic `List<T>`)
along with an implementation of `IndexMut<usize>`
for consistency with other containers.
I would rename the operation you implemented (`get_node`?)
and perhaps make it return an `Option` instead of panicking.

> ```rust
> .expect("line should have {index} more elements")
> ```

The panic message is literally `"line should have {index} more elements"` —
no substitution is performed for `{index}`,
which is probably not intended.
(In fact, such implicit named arguments only work within the formatting macros
`format!`, `print!`, `write!`, etc.).
The fix is

```rust
.unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("line should have {index} more elements"))
```

By the way, this is a clever panic message
as it mentions the quantity `index - len`,
which conveniently stays constant during the recursion.
The standard message is
`index out of bounds: the len is {} but the index is {}`,
for comparison,
which I personally find more informative.

> ```rust
> impl PartialEq for List {
>     fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
>         self.value == other.value && self.next == other.next
>     }
> }
> ```

This is equivalent to the default implementation of `PartialEq`,
which (along with a few other default trait implementations)
can be applied using `derive` when defining `struct List`:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Eq, Hash, Ord, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
pub struct List {
    // ...
}
```

> ```rust
> impl Display for List {
>     fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
>         if self.next.is_none() {
>             f.write_fmt(format_args!("{}", self.value))
>         } else {
>             f.write_fmt(format_args!("{} -> ", self.value))?;
>             std::fmt::Display::fmt(&self.next.as_ref().unwrap(), f)
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

The same `is_none` + `unwrap` anti-pattern is present here.

`f.write_fmt(format_args!("{}", self.value))` should be

```rust
write!(f, "{}", self.value)
```

Also, fully qualifying `std::fmt::Display` is not necessary.

For comparison, the containers in the standard library do not implement `Display`,
since there is no one true format suitable for user-facing display.
Better would be to support iterators and enable customizable formatters
such as [`itertools::format`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.format).

> ```rust
> impl From<Vec<u8>> for List {
>     fn from(vec: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
>         let mut result = List::new(vec[0]);
>         for item in &vec[1..] {
>             result.append(*item);
>         }
>         result
>     }
> }
> ```

The usual interface for such conversions is [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect),
which uses the [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) trait.
By implementing `FromIterator`, all kinds of iterators are supported,
not just `Vec`:

```rust
impl FromIterator<u8> for List {
    fn from_iter<I>(iter: I) -> Self
    where
        I: IntoIterator<Item = u8>,
    {
        let mut iter = iter.into_iter();
        let mut list = List::new(iter.next().expect("empty lists are not supported"));
        for item in iter {
            list.append(item);
        }
        list
    }
}

// ...
let list = List::from_iter([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]);
```